# Any hack on fixing one side of earphone

Tags: sound, wire

The left side of my earphone is not producing any sound. 
My last resort would be replacing it and disposing the defective earphone. 
Is there any way in order to make it work? When you create a power extension, you would just splice the wires and reconnect it, any similar hacks are appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

It might be because the soldering in that side might have gone off. You could fix that. This solution requires a pre requisit that you know how to do soldering. If not, you would better go for an electrician who knows this.

1. Using paper knife, carefully open ear piece.
2. You will see something like this
   [image]
3. You could see two wires each entering to each ear Piece
   [image]
4. Solder the one that seems to be disconnected.
5. Close the lids of ear piece as opened. Since they are so small, please be carefull while doing this as there is a chance for you to break them too.
6. If required, you can also glue them up with [fevi quick](http://www.robokart.com/image/cache/catalog/FEVI%20QUICK-500x500.jpg)(or similar har d glue enough for plastics) if caps of head phones does not fit each other.

Comment: Is the wiring similar to all earphones?

Comment: @GNMercado Yes, most of the earphones have similar wiring. But before pretending so, I suggest you to enquire about that from various resources in internet. If possible, try to search with model number. As you have not specified the model number here, I could answer for a general one only.

Comment: Often there is a break at the plug end in the cable.

Comment: @MANEESHMOHAN I'll check the model when I get home. Thanks

Comment: @Batman It's a wire only no button or whatsoever. :)

Comment: @GNMercado - thats not really relevant. Basically, if theres not a path from the plug to the earphone itself, there won't be sound. This often happens where near where the cable joins the plug, or near where the cable goes into the earphone.